# Processing a dataframe with another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames: df1 and df2. They both include information like 'ID', 'Name', 'Score' and 'Status', which I need is to update the 'Score' in df1 if that person's status in df2 is "Edit", and I also need to drop the row in df1 if that person's status in df2 is "Cancel".

For example:

```
dic1 = {'ID': [1, 2, 3],
       'Name':['Jack', 'Tom', 'Annie'],
       'Score':[20, 10, 25],
       'Status':['New', 'New', 'New']}

dic2 = {'ID': [1, 2],
       'Name':['Jack', 'Tom'],
       'Score':[28, 10],
       'Status':['Edit', 'Cancel']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(dic1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dic2)
```

The output should be like:

```
ID  Name  Score  Status
1  Jack     28    Edit
3  Annie    25    New
```

Any pointers or hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join first and then filter out `Cancel` rows and also columns ending with `_` from original `DataFrame`:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on=['ID','Name'], how='left', suffixes=('_', ''))
df = df.loc[df['Status'] != 'Cancel', ~df.columns.str.endswith('_')]
print (df)
   ID  Name  Score Status
0   1  Jack     28   Edit
```

EDIT Add [`DataFrame.combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) for repalce missing rows:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on=['ID','Name'], how='left', suffixes=('', '_'))
df = df.loc[df['Status_'] != 'Cancel']

df1 = df.loc[:, df.columns.str.endswith('_')]
df = df1.rename(columns=lambda x: x.rstrip('_')).combine_first(df).drop(df1.columns, axis=1)
print (df)
    ID   Name  Score Status
0  1.0   Jack   28.0   Edit
2  3.0  Annie   25.0    New
```

Comment: What if there is another person in df1 and it's not in df2, and I want to keep that person's information in the output?

Comment: @CherylCAI - Answer is more complicated, please check edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use pandas.DataFrame.update commnad of pandas package.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html

```
df1.update(df2)
print(df1)
df1 = df1[df1.Status != "Cancel"]
print(df1)
```